# Visual C++ program for paint brush code using openGL

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, paint, brush

I want the code/program for paint brush in Visual C++ using open gl.It must include square,rectangle,triangle,circle,pencil,eraser and it must have buttons.

Comment: While I'm sure there are people here who'd be happy to help you write such a program, I doubt that anybody's going to just give you code for a complete program.

Comment: Is it a homework questions? If so, this place is not for that!

Comment: This is not a question, but a wish.

Comment: Haha good one, made me laugh. This "question" is so nonsense that ill favorite it.

Comment: Haha, nice try. You forgot to mention layers and clipping mask.

Answer (score 4):

Not VC++, but a mix of C and C++
http://www.gimp.org/source/#source